# php $_SESSION with Switch

Tags: php, duplicates

I want to make a `$_SESSION` value, it does it but only in a normal page. If I use switch/case I can't get the value. Can somebody help me?

The switch/case:

```
switch($_GET['act'])
  {
        case 'login':                    
              include('./include/login.php'); break; 
        case 'logout':                    
              include('./include/logout.php'); break;      
        case 'help': 
              include('./include/help.php'); break;
        case 'help2': 
              include('./include/help.php'); break;                                                    
        case 'contact': 
              include('./include/contat.php'); break;
        case 'admin': 
              include('./include/admin.php'); break;
        case 'moderate': 
              include('./include/moderate.php'); break;                   
        case 'check': 
              include('./include/check.php'); break;             
        case 'belevki': 
              include('./include/belevki.php'); break;
        case 'register': 
              include('./include/register.php'); break;            
        case 'ls': 
              include('./include/ls.php'); break;      
        case 'los': 
              include('./include/los.php'); break;   
        case 'profile': 
              include('./include/profile.php'); break;          
        case 'srok': 
              include('./include/check1visrok.php'); break;
        default: // разглеждане на index-a
              include('./include/index.php');
  }
```

this is the code which i want to make the link from the creation of the session

```
$egn = $_POST['student'];
     validegn($egn);
$_SESSION['favcolor'] = $egn;
header("location:../index.php");
```

and this is the last page in which i want to display the value

```
$egn = $_SESSION['favcolor'];
echo $_SESSION['favcolor'];
```

Comment: Maybe u need to start session before accessing var? @session_start();

Comment: i have session_start(); everywhere

Answer (score 0):

When you do a redirect via `header('location: ../index.php)`, you drop all $_GET values. This is separate from the $_SESSION values and `session_start()`, it works that way even if you do not use sessions at all.

On the first page, do instead:

```
header("location:../index.php?act=help");'
```

for example. This will preserver your GET parameters and your switch will work. You might want to write a function that dynamically creates your redirect address.

On the second page (which has `switch($_GET['act'])`, you will then receive the `act` parameter.

Simplifying and summing up:

- `$_SESSION` is available after `session_start()`
- `$_GET` will contain values that the previous page passed via URL, like *http://foo.com?firstParam=1&secondParam=2*
- `$_POST` will contain values sent via `<form method='post'>...</form>`.

You see now that `session_start()` and `switch()` are unrelated in your case, because you use `$_GET` in the switch statement. You just need to pass the `$_GET` parameters correctly, then you're good.

Comment: Where should i put it, on the page which generates the value or the page with the switch or the last page which should use the value?

Comment: Hi, I've updated my answer. If you need anything else, just drop me a note.

Comment: Is it a problem for you to give me a example how should i put them in place? Sorry if it's problem. :(

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you need, like this? Sorry the comments don't support syntax highlighting.
  
_Page1_
    //calculate $egn
    $egn = $_POST['student'];
    validegn($egn);
    
    //save $egn to session
    start_session();
    $_SESSION['favcolor'] = $egn;
    
    //all saved, now redirect (as an example, I chose always 'help')
    header("location:../index.php?act=help");

_Page2_  
    //include the right file based on 'act' parameter
    switch($_GET['act']) {...} 

    //display stuff from the session
    start_session();
    echo $_SESSION['favcolor'];

Comment: No this doesn't work, i just need from page 1 which is the second code box to transfer through the switch to tha last code box. If it's a problem for you leave it. Thank you very much for the help anyway, i appreciate it!

Comment: You are mixing $_SESSION and $_GET. To pass anything between one page and another using $_GET, you *must* include the variables in the target address, see my previous comment. To pass anything to another page using $_SESSION, you *must* use session_start() before you access the session. That's really all there is to it. Your switch statement will then work (you didn't even need to post it, it is fine).